# Can't get hamster and getting things gnome integrate

Tags: 11.10, hamster

I'm on a 11.10 x64 machine.
When I open a task in gtg, hamaster didn't automatically add if I don't do it manully.
Hamster can read the titles and tags of my tasks.
But when I finish a task in gtg, hamster didn't stop tracking it.

I've add the gtg-daily ppa but nothing works.
BTW, I also added the ppa albertomilone/hamster-indicator for the hamsrer-indicator.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use gtg-daily ppa, the DBus API of GTG has changed (that is the reason why hamster can't get your tasks from GTG). I've reported the bug on your behalf: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtg/+bug/875821

The other thing is that, the hamster plugin doesn't stop tasks tracking in hamster in any case. (There is no code for that)
There is already opened a bug for that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtg/+bug/487582

Feel free to subscribe to those bugs to get informed about the newest changes.